# Android Text-To-Speech speak Cantonese with "alphabet" programmatically

Tags: android, internationalization, google-text-to-speech

I would like to speak "A13" with "A" pronounced in "English" and "13" in "Cantonese"; Below is the code I used but it just gives me "13" in Putonghua.

```
tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
tts.speak("A", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

tts.setLanguage(Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE);
tts.speak("13", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

I have followed the link below and installed the tts package for "cantonese", but I still would not set "Cantonese" in my app. However, if I use Ekho tts  engine, it would achieve the desired result but the voice is a bit strange versus google engine.

http://www.android-apk.com/2015/07/google-tts-%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E8%BD%89%E8%AA%9E%E9%9F%B3%E5%B7%B2%E6%94%AF%E6%8F%B4-%E7%B2%B5%E8%AA%9E-%E5%92%8C-%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to try `tts.setLanguage(new Locale("zh", "HK"))` or `tts.setLanguage(new Locale("yue", "HK"))`.
TRADITIONAL_CHINESE most likely refers to the writing, not to the spoken language. Taiwan for example uses traditional writing, but the spoken language is Mandarin (zh_TW). Cantonese is spoken in Hong Kong, therefore the "HK" variant should be used. Recent changes in Google's tts consider Cantonese ("yue") to be a different language altogether.

Comment: Hi Peter: new Locale("yue", "HK") works for my nexus phone but not for the other one. Many thanks!

Comment: Nice, I used "yue_HK" for TTS and "zh_HK" to do speech recognition with RecognizerIntent.